# Looking for a way to translate(i18n) laravels form validation rules inside a Vue form

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I have build an form in laravel with Vue with some validation rules and this works, when there's an error it will show me an message but I also have an locales switcher present which also works for the text in the form but not for the validation output, so there are always in English. I am using the [i18n](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/)
plugin to translate the text.

Is there a way to make the validation rules i18n ready?

**registerController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $customMessages = [
        'name' => 'some custom message can go here...',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'min:2', 'string', 'max:100'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => [
            'required'
            'min:10',
            'regex:/[a-z]/',      // must contain at least one lowercase letter
            'regex:/[A-Z]/',      // must contain at least one uppercase letter
            'regex:/[0-9]/',      // must contain at least one digit
            'regex:/[@$!%*#?&]/', // must contain a special character
        ],

    ], $customMessages);

    return $validator;
}
```

**componentForm.vue**

```
<template>

        <form @submit.prevent="formSubmit">            
           
            <el-input type="text" name="name" v-model="fields.name" 
                            label="Name" :error="errors.name"/>  

            <el-input type="email" name="email" v-model="fields.email" 
                            label="E-mailaddress" :error="errors.email"/>

            <el-input type="password" name="password" v-model="fields.password" 
                            label="Password" :error="errors.password"/>
        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn--xl btn--block">
                {{ $t("auth.register") }}
            </button> 
            
        </form> 

</template>

<script>

import espressoLocale from '../../Components/Contextual/Locale';
import espressoCard from '../../Components/UI/Card';
import elInput from '../../Components/Forms/Input';


export default {
    components: {
        elInput, 
    },
    data() {
        return {
          fields:{
              name: "",
              email: "",
              password: "",       
            },
            errors: {
                name: null,
                email: null,
                password: null,
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        resetFields () {
            this.fields.name = "";
            this.fields.email = "";
            this.fields.password = "";
        },
        formSubmit (e) {
            e.preventDefault();        
            this.errors = {};
            axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/api/register', 
                    data: {
                        name: this.fields.firstname,     
                        email: this.fields.email,
                        password: this.fields.password, 
                    },
                    validateStatus: (status) => {
                        return true; 
                    }
                }).then(response => {   
                    if (response.data.success) {                        
                    } else {
                        this.errors = response.data.errors || {};                                               
                    }
                }).catch(function (error) { });
            });            
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write `:error="$t(errors.name)"` in your components as you write `{{ $t("auth.register") }}` to show translated text about register. *I assume that you get i18n locale structured object in your errors response, something like this:*

```
errors: {
 name: 'errors.name',
 ...
}
```